# How to add text in TextInput after editing ends React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a URL textInput in my react native application. When user types URL without specifying URL protocol (e.g 'www.google.com') I need to automatically add 'http://' to it (http://www.google.com) after user ends input. Here is my code:

```
          onChangeText={url => {
               this.setState({ classUrl: url });
          }}
          onEndEditing={() => {
            if (this.state.classUrl.indexOf('http') === -1) {

              this.setState(
                { classUrl: `http://${this.state.classUrl}` },
                () => {
                  console.log(this.state.classUrl)
                }
              );
            }
          }}
         value={this.state.classUrl}
```

My component state changes and it updates the URL, however changes don't get displayed on UI.

Comment: Why not just set the default state to `http://`?

Comment: Will do that way if I won't be able to find any other solution. It's interesting why state gets updated, but value prop doesn't though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `onEndEditing` --->[link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onendediting)

```
<TextInput
    onChangeText={url => {
        this.setState({ classUrl: url });
    }}
    onEndEditing ={()=> {
        this.setState({ classUrl: 'https'+this.state.classUrl });
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Have tried that way, result is the same.. Url gets updated, but TextField's value prop doesn't get updated. If I save and open my component again it will show correctly.

Comment: try this one ```onEndEditing```, as suggested above

Comment: try this one ```onEndEditing```, as suggested above

Comment: that is what I am using. See the code snippet in my question